# "list indices must be integers or slices, not list" when trying to explore a list made of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
t1 = [[[None,2,None],5,[None,5,None]],6,[None,7,[None,8,None]]]

def recherche_iteratif(t,k):
    """ Même fonctionnement que recherche_recur mais en itératif """
    if t == None:
        return t
    for i in t:
         if k in t[i]:
            return t[i]
```

gives me

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

I don't fully understand how it works, I could do a load of fors to check if it's a list and if not THEN check but I'm sure there's an easier way

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to find the sub-tree?(sorry if that aint the word I'm not a native speaker) where k is the root. For example, in t1,  if I give 2 I want "[None,2,None]", 5 "[[None,2,None],5,[None,5,None]]", etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
def recherche_iteratif(t,k):
    """ Même fonctionnement que recherche_recur mais en itératif """
    temp = t
    while True:
       if temp == None:
          return None
       if k == temp[1]:
          return temp
       elif k > temp[1]:
          temp = temp[2]
       else:
          temp = temp[0]
```

Comment: Same thing as the other one, "if k in t[i]:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable", not sure why

Comment: @Kirout Can you please explain more what do you want do to.

Comment: I want to find the sub-tree?(sorry if that aint the word I'm not a native speaker) where k is the root. For example, in t1, if I give 2 I want "[None,2,None]", 5 "[[None,2,None],5,[None,5,None]]", etc...

Comment: @Kirout edited the answer. This will print the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your list

```
t = [[[None,2,None],5,[None,5,None]],6,[None,7,[None,8,None]]]
```

- first element : [[None,2,None],5,[None,5,None]] > is a list
- second element : 6 is an int
- third element : [None,7,[None,8,None]] again an list

you will need to add a check for element type like

```
if type(t[i]) != list : check if none
else : for j in t[i] : check if j is none
```

Check if this works

```
def recherche_iteratif_r(t,u):
  if t == None:
    return "t"
  if type(t) is list :
    if u in t :
      print(t)
    else :
      for i in t :
        recherche_iteratif_r(i,u)
```

Comment: seems like you need to use recursion

Answer (score 0):

```
def recherche_iteratif(t, k):
""" Même fonctionnement que recherche_recur mais en itératif """
if t is None:
    return t
for i in range(0, len(t)):  # here's what you need to correct
    if type(t[i]) == int:
        if k == t[i]:
            return t[i]
    elif type(t[i]) == list:
        if k in t[i]:
            return t[i]
        else:
            answer = recherche_iteratif(t[i], k)
            if answer:
                return answer
    else:
        if k is t[i]:
            return t[i]
```

You also need to perform a check at every point due to the type of list you have. That was the extra stuff I added. This would work even if a string is present in the list. Since you need to get into the inner list, this should work fine.

Comment: Oh that's very close to working, it doesnt work for like, 2 and 8 for some reason, imma try to work on it and edit it if I do manage to find the solution!

Comment: Ooh yeah, i just saw that but then that would be because there was an inner list. The 'in' keyword would usually just intrate through, so it wouldn't open up the inner list.

Comment: I have updated my answer, it works well I believe. Try it out